# Most efficient of using 'if'

Tags: php, algorithm

Code 1 :

```
if( !(varOfsomeClass->isValid($imParams)) ){
    //some function i need to run
}
```

- run function isValid
- reverse value with not (!)
- check value with if

Code 2 :

```
if( (varOfsomeClass->isValid($imParams)) ){
} else {
    //some function i need to run
}
```

- run function isValid
- check value with if
- enter else part(maybe, or do nothing because isValid is true)

which is more efficient? which is better to use?

nb: Code 1 is indeed more 'human'

Comment: Write the code that is actually understandable.. there is *no justification* to worry about 'most efficient' here, especially in context of PHP. (Note: some languages have an `unless`, which is an inverted-`if`, but PHP and other C-ish dialects do not.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize

Comment: The first and most important thing is that php variables start with `$`. Second is that your question doesn't hold any use whatsoever. Dont ask questions just to ask.

Comment: Simply measure if there is a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would say example #1 is more efficient, but I doubt this type of micro-optimization will give you performance gains even measurable in micro seconds, so it's not worth it.

Remember, the `if()` itself evaluates the expression passed to it for truthly/false values, so adding `!` is only redundant in most cases.

In other words, why would you need to do:

```
$number = 1; 
if(!$number){}
```

instead of this.

```
$number = 1; 
if($number){}
```

unless you are trying to *quickly* output something if `$number` is `false`,  then move on to something else, it does not make any sense to use the first one.

Answer (score 1):

```
if( !(varOfsomeClass->isValid($imParams)) ){
    //some function i need to run
}
```

This type code use Less resource when comparing with code 2 type.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not doing anything in the case `isValid` returns true. I would recommend to stick with the first version, where you only have a single `if` statement, for multiple reasons:

- Less code to read, easier to understand
- Leaving an empty block can be interpreted as "code not finished" for other contributors

Technically speaking, except a `JUMP` assembly instruction saved maybe (depending on the interpreter), both code will be as efficient... Do not try to think about those micro-optimization if it makes the code less readable.

Comment: *cough* PHP *cough*

Comment: yeah, changed compiler for interpreter, indeed :-)

Answer (score 0):

An interesting question.
I would suggest to put it in this mini test suite and test it out:

```
$startA = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++)
{
    //Code 1
}
$endA = microtime(true);

unset ($all, $your, $variables);

$startB = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++)
{
    //Code 2
}
$endB = microtime(true);

echo $endA-$startA."<br />";
echo $endB-$startB."<br />";
```

Comment: `0.00024104118347168 //using ! operator`
`0.00018596649169922 //using else`

Comment: have you run it multiple times? The results may vary and only many runs will show you a "trend"

Comment: yeah ran multiple times

Comment: then you should have your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

They are both equaly effective.

The first on needs an additional `!` negate statement, the second on has an additional `else` statement. The C code php uses is very effective when handling if/else constructs. It might even be the case that the second statement will get reduced to something similar like the first function in the ast parser.

However the second one is less readable an I would prefere the first one.

Answer (score 0):

The best using if is depend on how you need your return value,

1. If you need return value **not condition (reverse / false)** only, u could use :

   ```
   if ( ! varOfsomeClass->isValid( $imParams ) ){
       //some function you need to run
   }
   ```
2. If you need the **right (true)** return value, then use :

   ```
   if ( varOfsomeClass->isValid( $imParams ) ){
       // some function you need to run true
   }
   ```
3. If you need **true and false (both)** return value, then use :

   ```
   if ( varOfsomeClass->isValid( $imParams ) ){
       // some function you need to run true
   } else {
       // some function you need to run false
   }
   ```

And for your note, don't ever use this :

```
if ( varOfsomeClass->isValid( $imParams ) ){
} else {
    //some function you need to run
}
```

That's what you called not 'human', it's like you are light but u are doing dark. :)